# rsqlite_query_send: could not execute1: unable to open database file

Tags: r, sqlite, r-dbi, rsqlite

I'm hitting this weird database connection issue with `RSQLite` that I need to work around somehow.  I have documented how to reproduce this issue at the link below:

https://github.com/rstats-db/RSQLite/issues/101

```
> dbSendQuery(db, "create table hfp as select * from hfp_pac as a inner join ac as b on a.h_seq = b.ph_seq AND a.ppposold = b.ppposold")
Error in sqliteSendQuery(conn, statement) : 
  rsqlite_query_send: could not execute1: unable to open database file
```

Here is the db connection

```
> summary(db)
<SQLiteConnection>
  SQLite version:      3.8.6
  Database name:      
  Loadable extensions:
  File open flags:    
  VFS:                
>
```

I have tried following other `SQLite`-based stackoverflow questions where users hit the `unable to open database file` error, but they all say you must explicitly set the full filepath - and this has been no help either.

If anyone could help diagnose why I'm hitting this bug so that I can work around it, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Maybe you could narrow down the issue? The source file of yours is huge.

Comment: Can you include the connection line as well? If I am reading your link, I am seeing `conn` but here refers to `db`.

Comment: @tonytonov i tried.  but it only happens after a bunch of different processes run.  this was the smallest reproducible example i could create